# I can no longer log into my Ubuntu server anymore

Tags: server, ssh, login, password

I have a dedicated server that sits at home and is not public, running Ubuntu server. I normally tested game servers and websites on it. One day I went onto `putty`, my ssh client, and for some reason had trouble signing in. Then I went to the server itself and hooked up a monitor and keyboard and tried signing in from there and still could not login.

I restarted the system many times and still had the same result. It says (access denied). But for whatever reason I can login using my root account. My root password is the same password I use for my normal account. So I know my password isn't incorrect. And I know my username is correct as well. I've signed into this server many times without a problem. I'm stuck and have no clue on why and how this is happening.

Comment: you can use `passwd` from the root account to reset your password

Comment: Anyway you shouldn't have the same passwd for your root account ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passwords of other users are not available (easily) even to root. They are hashed in the `/etc/passwd` database and `/etc/shadow` as well.

Your best bet here is to reset the password of your user with `passwd` like Android Dev suggested in the comments:

```
sudo passwd <yourusername>
```

and follow the on-screen steps to set a new password.